# How to generate formatted week strings from start and end dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to generate a set like this:

```
April 1 2010  
April 8 2010  
April 15 2010  
April 22 2010  
April 29 2010  
May 6 2010
```

and so on.

from a startdate and an end date using only SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recurse over a CTE:

```
declare @start datetime = '1 apr 2010'
declare @end   datetime = '6 may 2010'

;with weeks(wdate) as
(
    select @start as wdate

    union all

    select 
        dateadd(week, 1, wdate)
    from weeks
        where wdate < @end
)
select wdate
    from weeks 

2010-04-01 00:00:00.000
2010-04-08 00:00:00.000
2010-04-15 00:00:00.000
2010-04-22 00:00:00.000
2010-04-29 00:00:00.000
2010-05-06 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I recommend not using regional/language-specific formats like 'd mmm yyyy' but rather use ISO standard date formats like 'yyyymmdd' that are guaranteed not to break regardless of server/user settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't worked with CTEs before - Is it possible to join onto this somehow or read it into a table variable?

Comment: The expression is a table so right after the CTE - after the closing ) - you can reference it by its name, i.e. `select x,y,x,wdate from weeks inner join blah ....`

Comment: Edit; note you can only do that once before it goes out of scope; after a `select wdate from weeks` another `select wdate from weeks` would fail